# The modulus of curve family

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I'm reading the book *Geometric Function Theory and Non-linear Analysis*, and there is one thing that I did not understand.

> A curve family $\Gamma$ is a collection of curves. An admissible density is a Borel function $\rho$ for which  $$\int_\gamma\rho\,ds\geqslant 1 \text{ for all } \gamma \in \Gamma$$ The modulus of $\Gamma$ is  $$M(\Gamma) = \operatorname{inf}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\rho^n(x)\,dx$$ where the infimum is over all admissible densities for $\Gamma$.

The property I do not understand is

> If $\Gamma$ contains a single "constant curve", then $M(\Gamma) = \infty$.

I thought "constant curve" is just a point in $\mathbb R^n$. But what are admissible densities in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gamma$ is a constant curve, the condition $\int_\gamma \rho\, ds\ge1$ cannot be satisfied because the integral is always zero. Therefore, there are no admissible densities for a curve family with a constant curve. In the definition of the modulus we have infimum taken over an empty set, and $\inf \emptyset =+\infty$.